# Does data transfer between EC2 and S3 travel over the public internet or internally on AWS networks?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does the route of data between EC2 and S3 go over the public internet?

Or does it travel over AWS internal networks?

I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data traveling from an EC2 would leave your VPC via a NAT gateway and travel over the public internet to S3.

To have private connections between your EC2 and S3 your can set up a S3 [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints.html)